# How to access a XamDataGrid when executing a command from XamRibbon (MVVM)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, infragistics

This my first post on this forum. Please bear with me.

I have an `infragistics` `XamRibbon` with a `ButtonTool` that binds to a command in the view-model.

This command needs an access to a `XamDataGrid` reference and not the `DataContext`. How can I access this reference using `MVVM` ?

Please note that the `XamDataGrid` and `ButtonTool` are not in the same view.

## xaml

```
<igRibbon:XamRibbon x:Name="ribMyRibbon" Caption="Ribbon">           
    <igRibbon:XamRibbon.Tabs>
        <igRibbon:XamRibbonTabItem>                                                        
            <igRibbon:XamRibbonGroup>
                <igRibbon:ButtonTool  CommondTool="{Binding myCommand}">

                </igRibbon:ButtonTool>                       
            </igRibbon:XamRibbonGroup>
        </igRibbon:XamRibbonTabItem>
    </igRibbon:XamRibbon.Tabs>
</igRibbon:XamRibbon>
```

## C#

```
  public Class DemoViewModel

    {

     public ICommand DemoCommand { get; private set; }

     public DemoViewModel() 

    {

     DemoCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(myDemoAction);

    }
       private void myDemoAction(object A)
            {
               //Need a refrence to the XamDataGrid 
            }


    }
```

Comment: *"Need a refrence to the XamDataGrid in the view"* -- no, you don't. Your XamDataGrid should be bound to some collection property of `DemoViewModel`. Manipulate the collection or the items in the collection directly.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I'm not manipulating the XamDataGrid from the view Model. The xamDataGrid have built-in function to export data to excel. That function need a reference to the DataGrid and not the DataContext.

Comment: Then put the command in the view's codebehind and have it reference the `XamDataGrid` by name. The viewmodel should not know that any such thing as a `XamDataGrid` exists.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Please note I'm using MVVM. I want to avoid using code behind. The Grid and ButtonTool are not in the same view.

Comment: You seem unwilling to consider any solution that doesn't break MVVM. Some code belongs in codebehind. That's why codebehind exists: For when you need to write code that directly manipulates stuff in the view. One option here is to give the viewmodel an event something like `CSVExport`. The command stays on the VM, but just raises the event. The view that owns the grid adds a handler for the event:
 `((DemoViewModel)DataContext).CSVExport += SomeHandlerMethod;` `SomeHandlerMethod` is a code behind method in the view; it can reference the `XamDataGrid` by name and do the CSV stuff.